# I want to add a style or class using a script

Tags: javascript, html, css

1. I want to give the script to add "Class=C" to "Class=B" when "Class=A" has "position: absolute" style.

Or

2. I want to give the script so that when "Class=A" has the style "position: absolute", it adds the style "bottom: 0px" to "Class=B".

I'm not familiar with scripts.

I've tried the code attached below, but it doesn't work.

How do I give a script like 01 or 02?

please help..!

※I used a translator because I couldn't speak English. That is why my words may not be natural. Please understand.

```js
$(function(){ 
    if ($('.A').css('position' == 'absolute')) {
        $('.B').addClass('C');
    }
    else {
        $('.B').removeClass('C');
    }
});
```

Comment: The code snippet you've put uses Jquery, are you using it?

Comment: that part should be like: `.css('position') == 'absolute'`

Comment: @Xecuter34
I'm trying to use jQuery "2.1.3.min.js", can I use this version?
And is there any problem with the code??

Comment: @Diego De Vita
I fixed the code as below as you said but it doesn't work..TT

$(function(){ 
    if ($('.A').css('position') == 'absolute') {
        $('.B').addClass('C');
    }
    else {
        $('.B').removeClass('C');
    }
});

Comment: If there are multiple "A" elements on the page then your code will only check the first one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should work as you expect

```js
$(document).bind('DOMSubtreeModified', function () {
    if ($('.A').css('position') == 'absolute') {
        $('.B').addClass('C');
    }
    else {
        $('.B').removeClass('C');
    }
});
```

## Edit 1

The above code will run whenever the DOM structure changes.
The delay is caused by something on your side, after the dom changes it will call the above function.

## Edit 2

You could try this, but it may not work

```
$(document).bind('change', function () {
    if ($('.A').css('position') == 'absolute') {
        $('.B').addClass('C');
    }
    else {
        $('.B').removeClass('C');
    }
});
```

Comment: When I use the code you provided, "Class C" is added and removed!
But, there is a delay of about 2-4 seconds in adding and disappearing "Class C".
I wish there was no delay, but what should I do?
Thanks so much for the great answer!

Comment: @Yeppeuda read my update

Comment: The additionally updated "Edit 2" doesn't work..TT
The cause of the delay in "Edit 1" cannot be known unless you check the applied code, right?
Thanks a lot! Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8"> 
<title></title> 
<script src="https://cdn.staticfile.org/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<style>
    .A {
        position:absolute
    }   
    .C {
        color:red
    }
</style>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    if ($('.A').css('position') == 'absolute') {
        $('.B').addClass('C');
    }
    else {
        $('.B').removeClass('C');
    }
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<p class="A">如果你点我</p>
<p class="B">继续点我!</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).